# how to make a downloadable pdf which is stored in assets?

Tags: android

I'm searching for  some source code  which downloads files from assets.
To use in my application  which  I save my PDF files in assets. and The download button will appear if the user completed or finished the game.
I was only find the [Download a file to your android device from a remote server](http://dhruvvaishnav.blogspot.in/2013/05/download-file-to-your-android-device.html)

Comment: you want to download file..

Answer (score 0):

You can download files from internet without blocking `UI`. This example show how to download a image file from remote server. Just replace things like `url` and downloading `path`.

The code goes here:

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AndroidDownloadFileByProgressBarActivity extends Activity {

    // button to show progress dialog
    Button btnShowProgress;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ImageView my_image;
    // Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;

    // File url to download
    private static String file_url = "yoururl/file.jpg";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // show progress bar button
        btnShowProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgressBar);
        // Image view to show image after downloading
        my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
        /**
         * Show Progress bar click event
         * */
        btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // starting new Async Task
                new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Showing Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            return pDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to download file
     * */
    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread
         * Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                // Output stream
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
       }

        /**
         * After completing background task
         * Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

            // Displaying downloaded image into image view
            // Reading image path from sdcard
            String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.jpg";
            // setting downloaded into image view
            my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I only want the other user to download the PDF which I stored in assets. how should I make it ?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** Let us understand the problem first . You want the user to be able to download a file in the assets. I guess, if the game is completed then the user's details pertaining to that game session  will be stored there.

**Solution :** For that you need to write in assets.

Well, the problem is you can't write any file there as the assets folder is read-only at runtime.

So the  way of doing this is using [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) .
Other alternatives you may want to look into are Shared Perferences and using Cache Files also explained in the link above .

If your application needs to download dependency files from server, you can go for APK Expansion Files provided by android (http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html).

Comment: your right  but ,I will not stored the user details .
I  only stored the drawing  images which I convert in PDF .So that The user(kids) can download it then  they can  Colored that drawing if they want to printed it

Comment: Please help me.how  should I implement it?